# Cannot Output Odd-Index Array Values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a newbie and would like to create a function that takes in an array and returns only the values that have an odd index.  For example, given an array [1, 2, 3, 4], I would like to return 2, 4.

My code currently doesn't return any values and I can't figure out why.  Below is my code...any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
var odder = function(array) {
    var only_odds = []
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        only_odds.push(array[i])
    }
    return only_odds
}

//Below I test the code on my console; it returns 'undefined.'

console.log(odder[5, 3, 2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: You forgot parentheses, and not call odder. Right way: `console.log(odder( [5, 3, 2, 4, 6] ))`

Comment: You're not invoking your function. Comma operator `1, 2, 3` gives `3`. Bracket notation `foo[3]` accesses property `3` of `foo`. Together, `foo[1, 2, 3]` accesses property `3` of `foo`. You probably wanted `foo([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks! I'm just puzzled why this record with square brackets does not cause an error.

Comment: @stdob--, Because it tries to evaluate it as a property. It does not exist, so return undefined.

Comment: @Mouser Yes, thank you, already understood.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var odder = function(array) {
    var only_odds = array.filter(function(value, index){
    //value is the current selected value, while index refers to the current index.
    //value will not be used in this function, since we only want to test the index.
    return index % 2; // only the odd values will be returned.
    });
    return only_odds;
}

//encapsuled in parentheses to execute the function. Result will be [3, 4]
console.log(odder([5, 3, 2, 4, 6]));
```

This updated function is a bit optimized. It uses modulo (`%`). It tests if the index is odd or even. If odd the modulo operator will return `true`. `array.filter` then returns the values with an odd index.

I used [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here.

[`Modulo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation): Returns the remainder of a division. So `5 modulo 2` will give a remainder of `1`. Since `2 times 2 = 4 + 1 = 5`. The 1 will evaluate as truthy (true) in JavaScript. So `odd module 2` will evaluate `true` while `even modulo 2` evaluates `false`.